# How to delete option of autocomplete antd

Tags: autocomplete, antd

I want to have a delete icon next to the antd autocomplete options to delete those options
and here is my code

```
 const options = [{ value: 'Burns Bay Road' }, { value: 'Downing Street' }, { value: 'Wall Street' }]
return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmut}>
          <AutoComplete
            options={options}
            filterOption={(inputValue, option) => option!.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue.toUpperCase()) !== -1}
          >
            <Input
              value={searchText}
              maxLength={50}
              onKeyPress={(event) => {
                if (/[0-9]/.test(event.key)) {
                  event.preventDefault()
                }
              }}
              className={styles.input}
              style={{ width: 364, height: 44, padding: 12 }}
              placeholder='Search..'
              onChange={handleChangedSearchText}
            />
          </AutoComplete>
          <Button
            htmlType='submit'
            className={styles.button_search}
            style={{ width: 44, height: 44 }}
            icon={<SearchOutlined style={{}} className={styles.icon_search} />}
          />
        </form>
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k0YA.png)

I'm waiting for your reply, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods to customize select option. If you are using antd@5.11.0 or above, use `optionRender`. Second option is to map over options and use label to customize the option.

**Method: 1**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { AutoComplete, Button, Input } from 'antd';
import { CloseOutlined, SearchOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const App = () => {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([{ value: 'Burns Bay Road' }, { value: 'Downing Street' }, { value: 'Wall Street' }]);

    return (
        <form style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <AutoComplete
                options={options}
                filterOption={(inputValue, option) => option!.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue.toUpperCase()) !== -1}
                optionRender={(option) => {
                    return (
                        <span style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                            <span>{option?.value}</span>
                            <Button
                                danger
                                size='small'
                                type='text'
                                icon={<CloseOutlined />}
                                onClick={(e) => {
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                    setOptions((prev) => prev.filter((item) => item.value !== option.value));
                                }}
                            />
                        </span>
                    );
                }}
            >
                <Input style={{ width: 364, height: 44, padding: 12 }} placeholder='Search..' />
            </AutoComplete>
            <Button htmlType='submit' style={{ width: 44, height: 44 }} icon={<SearchOutlined />} />
        </form>
    );
};

export default App;
```

**Method: 2**

```
import { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { AutoComplete, Button, Input } from 'antd';
import { CloseOutlined, SearchOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const App = () => {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([{ value: 'Burns Bay Road' }, { value: 'Downing Street' }, { value: 'Wall Street' }]);

    const selectOptions = useMemo(() => {
        return options.map((option) => {
            return {
                ...option,
                label: (
                    <span style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                        <span>{option?.value}</span>
                        <Button
                            danger
                            size='small'
                            type='text'
                            icon={<CloseOutlined />}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                setOptions((prev) => prev.filter((item) => item.value !== option.value));
                            }}
                        />
                    </span>
                )
            };
        });
    }, [options]);

    return (
        <form style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <AutoComplete
                options={selectOptions}
                filterOption={(inputValue, option) => option!.value.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputValue.toUpperCase()) !== -1}
            >
                <Input style={{ width: 364, height: 44, padding: 12 }} placeholder='Search..' />
            </AutoComplete>
            <Button htmlType='submit' style={{ width: 44, height: 44 }} icon={<SearchOutlined />} />
        </form>
    );
};

export default App;
```